# How to submit a Celery task from Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, rabbitmq, celery

I am currently migrating a python application to use Celery (using RabbitMQ) however I need to enqueue the tasks from a ruby program (to be then executed by the python application).

Is there an easy way to either pass a message in the right format to RabbitMQ or a gem available for simply queueing the job?

(I've looked into [RCelery](https://github.com/leapfrogonline/rcelery) however it seems a bit outdated and not sure if this is exactly the solution I'm looking for)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a Ruby-specific solution out there, but one option is that you can submit tasks via HTTP pretty easily. This is mentioned at the very end of the [Webhooks Guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/remote-tasks.html#guide-webhooks) and points to an [HTTP Gateway Example](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/celery_http_gateway/) that is based on the [djcelery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery) library.

Comment: ooo, that is ver very briefly mentioned at the very very end of that page. it is easy to get all confused up with webhooks and stuff.